# Blocks display in the wrong place and can't be turned off

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm experiencing problems: Some of my blocks are appearing in two blocks at the same time. Some blocks appear when disabled, even if I disable the block is still appears in one of the locations. It's happening with several blocks but not all.

This is what the footer looks like:

[image: drupal block issue]

Drupal 7.34 running locally Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

The theme is BigWig

- Block caching is switched off. I've used the "Flush all caches"
  button and deleted everything in the cache DB table.
- I only have 4 blocks displaying, the "business info" (currently duplicated), "copyright info" (appearing correctly) and "main page content" and "System help".
- I've checked the theme code and the "Powered by Drupal" block is a block and not hard coded. But the block is disabled.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and all that?

Comment: @Darren Cleared the cache multiple times, both via admin/config/development/performance and mysql

Comment: Can't see the screenshot.

Comment: Not familiar with the theme. Have you got any other display plugins enabled eg context, panels, display suite?

Answer (score 2):

After nearly going insane I noticed that the module, "Context", was overriding my blocks.

Comment: This might help anyone else using the Bigwig theme: If you want node content displayed on the home page comment out line 150 in sites/all/themes/bigwig/template.php